# datatool sorting problem - wrong data type?

Tags: datatool, dimensions

I created a very small DB with `datatool` to store two values at each line of the table. First a running ID and second a generated dimension (converted to mm) which I calculated of the width of each input image I am going to register/save in this list.

After all images are registered, I want to sort the list first before I further process it. Unfortunately, `DTLsort` seams to interprets the number not as numbers but something else and so the resulting sorted list is not as expected.

As which data type do I need to insert the values of the image dimensions into the DB so that `DTLsort` can sort them correctly? Or is there any switch/flag I need to set so that `DTLsort` knows how to interpret the values of the column?
Here is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\dimtomm#1{\the\numexpr\dimexpr#1\relax*635/118407168\relax}

\newsavebox\imagebox
\newcommand{\regimg}[2]{%
  \sbox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{#1}}%
  \DTLnewrow{list}%
  \dtlexpandnewvalue%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#2}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{width}{\dimtomm{\wd\imagebox}}%
}

\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
  \DTLifdbexists{lists}{\DTLcleardb{lists}}{\DTLnewdb{lists}}%
}{%  
\DTLsort{width=descending}{list}
\DTLdisplaydb{list}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{sortedlist}
\regimg{img01.jpg}{1}
\regimg{img02.jpg}{2}
\regimg{img03.jpg}{3}
\regimg{img04.jpg}{4}
%...
\end{sortedlist}
\end{document}
```